# Please explain why the output does not change whatever be the value of i

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
 int i = 10;
 i=!i>14;
 printf("i=%d",i);
}
```

I get the output : i=0
I get the same output even when I change the value of **i** to any other integer.
What does this code do?
Please explain

Comment: As @DSM notes below, in addition to the operator precedence issue, your printf() statement is lacking the value to be printed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is likely to be closed soon.  Please note that your `printf()` statement is malformed; you should be providing a value to print, and you should probably have a newline at the end of the format string to guarantee that the output appears.  Also, the return type of `main()` is `int`, not `void`, and unless you're using a C99 or later compiler, you should include `return(0);` or equivalent at the end of the `main()` function.

Comment: Please put some minimal effort into learning the programming language before asking questions about it.

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
i=!i>14;
```

is parenthesized (implicitly)

```
i= (!i) > 14;
```

Since the result of a `!` is always either 0 (if `i != 0`) or 1 (if `i == 0`), the result is always smaller than 14.

Your `printf` call

```
printf("i=%d");
```

misses its second argument (thanks @DSM for spotting it), that invokes undefined behaviour, since each conversion specifier must have a corresponding argument of the correct type.

Comment: I think there's something off with the `printf` too..

Comment: Good spot, @DSM, included that.

Answer (score 3):

This statement: `i = !i > 14` assigns to the variable `i` the result of the expression: `!i > 14`.

`(!i) > 14` is *false* because `!i` is zero for any non-zero number, i.e. `0 > 14`. Since *false* is represented in C by `0`, `i` gets the value `0`.

Also, your `printf` call doesn't have a matching argument for the `%d` in the format string. The `printf` should be: `printf(i=%d\n", i);`

Answer (score 3):

Also, your `printf` call just specifies a format but is missing `i` as argument.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement the other answers:

There is an error in this line:

```
printf("i=%d");
```

It should be:

```
printf("i=%d",i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to precedence rules, that line reads as:

```
i = (!i)>14;
```

So, `i` is 10, which, for the `!` operator, is true; `!` negate this, giving false, i.e. 0, so what you get is `0>14`, which is obviously false, i.e. 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted this
i=!(i>14);
The logic you wrote resolves from left to right completely, first not(i) then it's result is tested against 14 for greater than.